# SQL - Is there a LIKE / Contains / Wildcard function when I don't have a specific criteria?

Tags: ms-access

EG:

Table A has a Name column
Table B has a Name column

I have used the below code for an exact match

```
SELECT Table_A.Name, Table_B.Name
FROM Table A, Table B
WHERE Table_A.Name = Table_B.Name;
```

Now I want to check if there are any columns that are similar.

I tried this.

```
SELECT Table_A.Name, Table_B.Name
FROM Table A, Table B
WHERE Table_A.Name LIKE '%Table_B.Name%';
```

I want to be able to pull up names in Table A that are similar to Table B. It's my understanding that the LIKE operator only works if you know what criteria you are looking for. So obviously the above statement doesn't work.

Is this possible or am I way off the mark?

Comment: 1) Please don't do tag spam. Select one database only as the solutions will probably be different. 2) For Postgres try,  `Table_A.Name ILIKE '%' || Table_B.Name || '%';`

Comment: Are you looking for an exact match between TableA and B? You may join the table on the `name` in that case.

Comment: And don't use comma join syntax, use explicit joins.

Comment: I've removing the conflicting RDBMS tags... feel free to add back the correct one.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this! Noting only one tag for future posts.

Comment: For your future notes: Only use tags that are relevant to your post. You can use more than one tag, but the tag must specifically apply to your question. Tag spamming is the use of tags that clearly are not, such as using multiple DBMS's when clearly you're only using a single database at a time, or tagging with multiple languages (e.g., VB, VBA, VB.Net) when you actually use only one of them. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works, as was suggested when you created your account.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax would work, but it is not exactly 'similar names'; it is if the name Table_B appears somewhere in Table_A.name:

```
SELECT Table_A.Name, Table_B.Name
FROM Table A, Table B
WHERE Table_A.Name LIKE '*' & Table_B.Name & '*';
```

Also the wildcard characters in MsAccess are not standard SQL, so they are `*` and `?`, replacing `%` and `_`, respectively.

For the scenario: Table A: Ted Smith Table B: Teddy Smith:

You can't use the LIKE operator to capture such senarios unless you also maintain a name-similarities table (and mark Ted as Teddy). Approximate name matching is a vast subject, there are algorithms for it like SOUNDEX and METAPHONE (search for them, there are VBA implementations you can use.) UPDATE:20220401: Forgot to add EDIT DISTANCE.
Here is one:http://www.allenbrowne.com/vba-Soundex.html

If you adopt a Soundex function you can use it like:

```
SELECT Table_A.Name, Table_B.Name
FROM Table A, Table B
WHERE SoundEx([NameA])=SoundEx([NameB])`.
```

Beware though; for large data-sets this will be slow!

I also sugegst that you read about the strengths/weaknesses of the algorithm, especially when used with names where first and lastname are combined. These algorithms are generally used in combination with other methods (like `LIKE`, and or other relevant information about the person, like address), and with user assistance (ie the possible matches are presented to an operator allowing her/him to choose).

Comment: Thanks for this! I gave it a go and am getting the same results as when I use `=`

If it helps, here is a scenario: 
**Table A:** Ted Smith  **Table B:** Teddy Smith 

How can I pull this up without entering a criteria?

Comment: I did a test in Immediate Window: `?Soundex("Ted Smith") = Soundex("Teddy Smith")` returns True. `?Soundex("Ted Smith") = Soundex("Rex Smith")` returns False. Query `SELECT DISTINCT Table1.NameA, Table2.NameB
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE (((SoundEx([NameA])=SoundEx([NameB]))=-1));`

Comment: I don't think you need the `=-1`. You can just use `WHERE SoundEx([NameA])=SoundEx([NameB])`. Beware though; for large data-sets this will be slow

Comment: This is great, thanks for being so helpful. I will do some research and see if I can apply it.